# How do I make my C program run faster?

Tags: javascript, c, node.js, performance

I know that this has something to do with the compiler but I'm completely stuck for where to go next. I'm working on a simple Monte-Carlo method pi calculator and I've found that node is around 2 times faster than C despite the fact that C should be much faster.

What exactly should I be doing to optimise my C build for speed at run-time? Here is my code just in case I missed something.

monteCarloPi.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int squareLen = 500;
    int squareArea = squareLen * squareLen;
    int radius = squareLen / 2;
    int radiusSqu = radius * radius;
    int x, y;
    int nInRad = 0, nTotal = 0;
    double pi;


    while(1) {
        nTotal += 1;
        x = abs((rand() % squareLen) - radius);
        y = abs((rand() % squareLen) - radius);

        if ((x*x) + (y*y) <= radiusSqu) {
            nInRad += 1;
        }

        if(nTotal % 100000000 == 0) {
            pi = ((double) nInRad / (double) nTotal) * squareArea / radiusSqu;
            printf("%lf\n", pi);
            printf("%d million monte carlo points\n\n", (nTotal / 1000000));
        }
    }
}
```

monteCarloPi.js

```
var nIn = 0, nTotal = 0;

monteCarlo();

function monteCarlo() {

    while(true){
        nTotal++;
        var xAbs = Math.abs((Math.random() * 500) - 250);
        var yAbs = Math.abs((Math.random() * 500) - 250);
        if((xAbs*xAbs) + (yAbs*yAbs) <= 250*250) {
            nIn++;
        } 

        if(nTotal % 100000000 == 0) {
            console.log(((nIn / nTotal) * 500 * 500) / (250*250));
            console.log((nTotal / 1000000) + ' million points');
            console.log('\n');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If this code works this question is better suited for [Code Review exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). But one thing as an example, it doesn't look like `squareArea` or `radiusSqu` change during the loop, so you should precompute the quotient `squareArea / radiusSqu`, although I'd expect the compiler to be doing this for you already if you have optimizations turned on.

Comment: for both cases, I'd also try to think of a way to replace the modulo-division comparison with a simple comparison, maybe loop over `nTotal` from 0 to 1000000000 and then your condition `if (nTotal == 1000000000)`.. or have nested loops where the inner is `while(nTotal < 1000000001)` and outside of that you do the printing and `nTotal` reset.

Comment: you could rewrite the C code to use vector intrinsics, if the compiler isn't doing it already.

Comment: In addition to the other good advice, consider unrolling the loop 10 times.

Answer (score 3):

When your C code is compiled with optimizations `-O3 -march=native` it runs faster (28% faster on my machine) than the JavaScript version.

```
gcc -O3 -march=native -Wall -Wextra -o monteCarloPi monteCarloPi.c
```

Answer (score 2):

> my question is what exactly should i be doing to optimise my C build for speed at run-time?

1. Make sure the optimization is enabled during the compilation with -O3 command line argument.
2. You should repeat the test enough time to make sure the results are reliable.
3. You should avoid any logging/printf because it is a huge noise factor.

> here's my code just in case i missed something.

The main reason you see quite similar results is because the `rand()` call is very expensive and it takes about the same time both in C and in JS. If you could avoid this call in the loop, you will immediately see the difference in favor of C.